# How to know the optimum salary

Tags: salary, hiring-process, india

I am from India.

I have 1.7 years of experience with my current salary as 650000 INR per annum.

I recently got an offer from Oracle Application Labs for Engineer Role with the Package between 400000 INR to 2000000 INR for 1 to 6 years of experience.

How to know which figure to ask between this large range?

I searched online and could not find a suitable answer for mine.

In India asking less will make you repent and asking more will keep you away from getting offer letter.

Answer (score 3):

In my career I follow one rule - always ask more than you have had before. Because you got more experience, more knowledge etc. Also I often ask 10%-15% more than I really "cost" because I want to have a buffer for salary negotiations. Don't worry your employer also does the same trick.

In your current situation I would ask for 750000 INR since your experince is not that much and it is more than you have now. Good luck!